# Are my petunias dying?

Tags: flowers

Can anyone tell what is wrong with my petunias? 
They get full sun and are watered regularly. I have been fertilizing them once every month with the fertilizer shown below
What should I do to make them healthier?

[image]
[image]
[image][image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Is the soil really wet?  Sometimes they will rot in wet soil. Did they get planted in the same soil you used last year? Pull out a few of the dead/dying plants and look at the stems at soil level. I've found that the plants will have rotted at the soil line and no roots will come up with the plant.